# How do I pass a string within an object literal in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have just learned about code organization with object literals, but I haven't been able to figure out how to pass a string variable within an object literal. 
This is my code kind of looks like:

```
var foo = {
    onReady : function() {
        $( '.adiv' ).click( foo.action( 'test' ) );
    },
    action : function( x ) {
        alert( x );
    }
jQuery( function($){
    foo.onReady();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a string"?  The word "pass" is generally used when talking about arguments to functions. Your code as posted has several syntax errors so it's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. Please indicate what problem you are having, and what would fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `.click()` must be a function. You're calling `foo.action` immediatel instead of passing a function that calls it. So it should be:

```
onReady: function() {
    $(".adiv").click(function() {
        foo.action('test');
    });
},
```

You're also missing the comma between elements in the object.

There's no problem with the way you pass a string to the function. Just put the string in quotes, and put that string literal in the function arguments.